# While cleaning Safari System Caches which files should be kept within the caches folder to prevent logging out of websites

Tags: macos, mac, safari

I use CleanMyMac 3 to clear caches ocassionaly on my mac, but I don't clear Safari caches often using CleanMyMac becuase I believe that clearing Safari caches logs you out of all the website you are currently logged into, logging into the websites again by entering passwords is a hit or miss scenario.

Luckily, CMM3 gives you the option to clear some parts of the file and leave the rest but I don't know which part of the Safari System Caches stores and remebers active logins. I am attaching a screenshot to give a better idea of all the cache files I am currently able to see.

If anyone can tell me which cache files to delete and which ones to keep then I can save myself from the hectic process of Logging in again to all the websites

[image]